# Box2D with cmake won't build a .lib file?

Tags: c++, cmake, box2d

I am trying to use cmake to build the box2d library for visual studio 2012. This is what I have in cmake:[image]

The `Box2D/Box2D` directory has all of the source files in it and the `Box2D/Build` directory is where I want to put all of the library things. I selected the visual studio 11 compiler and it compiled and generated without errors. However in the build folder I can't find any `.lib` file. This is what generates in the build folder:[image]

I went through all of these directories but not one had any box2d.lib file in them. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Help please?

Comment: What happened when you opened the Visual Studio project with Visual Studio 2012 and built the ALL_BUILD target?

Comment: @MasterID It does, but how do I generate a .lib? I have access to the header files of course, but there is no library file

Comment: You can get cmake to build visual studio projects if you open up the appropriate Visual Studio command prompt go inside the build folder and type cmake --build

Comment: @drescherjm I'll do that now (I'm new at this)

Comment: @drescherjm still no .lib file

Comment: I am sorry you probably need cmake --build . from the folder containing the sln file. However I see you said the project built so I am not sure this will help. I use cmake ever day for years on windows but do not use box2d.

Comment: @drescherjm Im gonna try and build some other stuff

Answer (score 1):

Cmake only generates the build files so you can build it with the tool you choose in cmake - `Visual Studio` in your case. It only generated the Visual Studio project files. You have to open those files to build your library.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I built some projects in Project.sln and some .lib files were generated. I was thinking cmake was supposed to do that for you.

Comment: Hmm. I thought you had already done that. I asked you about this 10 minutes ago on my first post..

Comment: @drescherjm That was a different project. I opened up another project later called "testbed" and built it. The first one didn't do anything

Comment: Testbed most likely is some type of unit testing. Normally for cmake based projects the generated sln file in the root folder of the build tree is the one to use.

Comment: I don't know but the ALL_BUILD target wasn't part of the Project.sln file. Thanks that will help me later on